# Filter observations starting with a number in an interval?

Tags: r

How do I select observations starting with a number in an interval (410*-420*)

```
Kode Operation                                
   <dbl> <chr>                                    
 1    10                        
 2 40020    
 3 41040                
 4 41150               
 5 41260        
 6 42080 
 7 43000
```

The result should then be:

```
 Kode Operation   


   <dbl> <chr>                                    

 3 41040                
 4 41150               
 5 41260        
 6 42080
```

Hope this isn´t a duplicate. Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: Is the number always going to be 5 digit. `subset(df, Kode %in% 41000:42999)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple math can help here no matter how many digit numbers you have (not just 5)

```
i1 <- x / 10 ^ ((nchar(x) - 3))
x[i1 >= 410 & i1 < 421]
#[1] 41040 41150 41260 42080
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c(10, 40020, 41040, 41150, 41260, 42080, 43000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
subset(df,Operation%/%100>=410 & Operation%/%100<=420)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Kode Operation
3    3     41040
4    4     41150
5    5     41260
6    6     42080
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Kode = 1:7, Operation = c(10L, 40020L, 41040L, 
41150L, 41260L, 42080L, 43000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidy-version:

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
mutate(Operation=as.double(Operation))%>%
filter(Operation %in% c(41000:42999))


# A tibble: 4 x 2
    Kode Operation
   <int>     <dbl>
1     3     41040
2     4     41150
3     5     41260
4     6     42080
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 410:420 have five digits, you could use `floor` after dividing by 100.

```
dat[floor(dat$Operation / 100) %in% 410:420, ]
#   Kode Operation
# 3    3     41040
# 4    4     41150
# 5    5     41260
# 6    6     42080
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Kode = 1:7, Operation = c(10L, 40020L, 41040L, 
41150L, 41260L, 42080L, 43000L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a solution that undependent from the total number of digits and easy to follow, you can also search for first 3 digits directly

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
x<- as_tibble(c(10, 40020, 41040, 41150, 41260, 42080, 43000))
x %>% mutate(first_three_numbers=(as.numeric(substr(value,1,3)))) %>%  
      filter(between(first_three_numbers,410,420))
```